# Selecting N elements from a list of (item,ID) , in the ratio of weights assigned to their IDs

Tags: algorithm, math, data-structures, statistics

So I have a large list of items ,each of which has an ID assigned . Now I need to pick N items from the list ,such that the ratio of the number of items from each ID is given.

Lets say:
There are 3 ids , and their weights are in the ratio - 1:3:2

so if N = 6 ,
I'll pick 1 item of id 1, 3 of id 2 ,and 2 of id 3

However in some cases there might not be enough items of a particular ID , in those cases it will have to be adjusted between the other ids.Total number of items picked has to be N.
One possible solution I thought of was to convert this problem to a weighted sampling problem. However converting the weights of the IDs to weights of each item would add a lot of complexity I believe .

Answer (score 0):

Conceptually it is not that difficult, although you will have to handle a few edge cases.

Compute the actual quantity of items needed for each `id` based on the ratio between the sum of your input ratios and the total requested quantity, `N`. You may have to take care of rounding issues, so one quantity (perhaps the largest one) may need to be adjusted.

Scan over your list, and for each `id` create a list of "selected" items which will go in the final result, and a list of "available" items which may be used later, in case some `id`s don't reach the requested quantity.

One possibility is, at a point all `id`s will have reached the requested quantity, in which case we don't even need to loop over the full input list.

If this is not the case, then compute how many items are still needed, recalculate the new ratios for the `id`s which have available items and use those items to reach the total requested quantity; repeat until `N` is reached.